# write (), отрубившийся сокет

Tags: linux, tcpclient

Нашёл пример по ТСР и сделал по нему свой.

Клиент:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    char buffer[256];
    if (argc < 3) {
       fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
       exit(0);
    }
    portno = atoi(argv[2]);
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");
    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
         (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
         server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
        error("ERROR connecting");
    printf("Please enter the message: ");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
    while(n>=0){
    n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
    if (n < 0) 
         error("ERROR writing to socket");
     }
    bzero(buffer,256);
    n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
    if (n < 0) 
         error("ERROR reading from socket");
    printf("%s\n",buffer);
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

Все работает ок, но как только я  уничтожу  сервер во время работы,  клиент вылетает на:

```
n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
```

То есть, конструкция типа:

```
while(1){
        n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
        if (n < 0) 
             error("ERROR writing to socket");
         }
```

также вылетает на `write ()`.

Как мне обработать эту ошибку?

P.S. работаю через localhost.

Comment: 1) Что значит "вылетает" ?По прерыванию вылетает, или завершается с кодом ошибки? 
2) А что Вы ожидаете?  У Вас потоковое соединение, которое было разорвано с другой стороны. Естественно, операции ввода/вывода на этом соединении принудительно завершаются ОС. Что не так ?

Comment: Разве write() в таком случае  не должен  просто вернуть -1 ?

Comment: Вот я и спрашиваю у TS - что он обозначает загадочным словом "вылетела" :-)